# Git shell prompts for password in an OpenSSH popup window

Tags: git, shell, github, git-shell

I don't know why, recently git shell asks me for credentials in an old-fashioned OpenSSH window (by the way, I use a https connection) instead of just prompting in the console.

That prevents me to use the wincred, I always have to type my credentials. Quite annoying, esecially that when I make a typo, the console cursor disappears. How can I go back to the default mode?

System: Windows 7

Console: ConEmu

[image: github openSSH window]

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `$ git config --global core.askPass ""`

You can also set credentials in your config to prevent being prompted every time (https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).

Answer (score 9):

This could be also caused by `Visual Studio Code`. If this is the case just add `"git.autofetch": false` into your `setting.json` file.